# Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, dbcontext

I am having this Error.
[image: Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute' ERROR]

The ApplicationDbContext is Auto Generated DbContext, used in account section. Whenever i try to use any Account Controller actions this error occurs.
    The error originates from

```
  public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
        }
```

I have my own DbContext which works fine and gets all the required Data.

The references are fine. How do i fix this issue.

**Update**
I used some updated Refrences for AspNet.Identity . is it causing the issue?

**Update 2**
This error occured when I was mixing two Membership provider versions. I first used the default provided with MVC 5 then tried to use MVC 3 membership, then again went back to MVC 5. Then this error started to pop up.

I still have not found the solution to this problem. **But as workaround**, I recreated the Project will all my previous files, and it worked.

Comment: hi , did u have any workaround for the above , i have the same issue

Comment: Any resolution? I also have the same problem.

Comment: I actually recreated the Project with same files (models, controllers, views) and it worked. Could not find the real solution  :/

Comment: Did some research and found this: `IndexAttribute is one of the new things included in EF 6.1. So the problem is that you are referring to the wrong version of the EF (6.0). `

Comment: also had this problem. I recreated the project and it work. Bit of a mission to do but .. i guess one should not play around to much with identity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit your `.csproj` file, and replace the `<HintPath>` values with the correct Entity Framework version paths (currently, the latest stable version is 6.1.2):

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Verify that the paths exist; if not, install the Nuget package for the version you want.

To be clear, these are the `<HintPath>` elements you want to edit to ensure have the current version:

```
<HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
```

and

```
<HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
```

Leave these set to the major version 6.0.0.0:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

And

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

Comment: Actually, it's 6.1.3, if you're using the most recent EF 6.

Comment: In Visual studio(2015) menu:Tools->Nuget package manager->Manage nuget packages for solution... you have an overview. In my case selected Entity framework in the left panel and immediately saw that one project used an old version of EF. Which also was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and I've tried to modify my `.csproj` file and replace the `<HintPath>` like what Chris Schiffhauer has showed above but the problem was not solved. Finally, I found out that entity framework dll in my GAC was an old version (6.0.0.0), after removing it, no more problem.

You can easily find it here C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with a test project, both projects had a reference to entity framework 6.0.0.0. I was able to solve it by removing and adding the reference to entity framework again in the test project.